# How to connect React.js frontend on EC2 with the backend Spring Boot REST API also on EC2 under the same subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I'm using AWS for hosting a demo project. I'm new to AWS and thus I might have made some foolish mistakes. The React.js frontend is hosted on the EC2 on the same subnet and same VPC as the Spring Boot backend EC2. The applications are all deployed using Docker, with the backend exposing port 8080 and frontend exposing port 3000.

At this moment, in security groups I'm exposing SSH from my IP Address, HTTP and HTTPS requests from anywhere for my frontend and I can use a web browser to have access to my frontend page. Also, when exposing my backend port to the internet by allowing security group HTTP from anywhere, I can get REST API responses from the backend server.

However, I do not want to expose my backend server to public IP address and wish the frontend server to able to communicate to the backend using the private IP address of backend. After editing the security group of backend to SSH from my IP address, TCP for port 3000 from security-group-3 (which the security group my frontend is using), I get the following error when browsing the webpage in browser:

http://[private address of backend]:8080/api/v1/player Error_Connection_Time_Out

What should I do to not exposing backend to public IP while being able to fetch responses from it using the frontend?

I've searched and found that React.js hosts static websites(?), and thus the REST API requests will be sent from the browser of the user. Is this correct and does this mean that I have to expose the backend port to the public? Is there a possiblity of using AWS ELB to direct traffic so that I do not need to expose the backend? Any suggestion would be much appreciated!